# Error when using textbox values inside string sql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, visual-studio-2010

`"Select item from table1 where Spare parts='"+ textbox1.text+"'"`.

I have tried to replace `item` with `Textbox2.text`.

I used :

```
"Select'"& textbox2.text& "' from table1 where Spare parts='"+ textbox1.text+"'"
```

I got error.

I used `"+ textbox2.text+"` I got error too

Comment: Welcome to SO, what's the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In very briefly I want to replace "item" in the sql string with a value from textbox to use it in Microsoft  accesses table

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is one of the fastest ways out there to get your app hacked. It is **NOT** how you include user input in an SQL statement.

To explain the right way, I also need to include the connection and command objects for context, so I may also have a different pattern for how I handle these than you're use to. I'm also assuming the `mysql` tag in the question is accurate (though I have my doubts), such that the correct code looks more like this:

```cs
string SQL = "Select item from table1 where `Spare parts`= @SpareParts";

using cn  = new MySqlConnection("connection string here")
using cmd = new MySqlCommand(SQL, cn)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SpareParts", TextBox1.Text);

    cn.Open();
    using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Note the backticks around `Spare Parts`, so it will be correctly treated as a single object name by MySql.

Comment: I don't have problem with "@SpareParts" but I have problem with "item" I want replace it with textbox.text but  the Application could not find  item in the Microsoft Acceses table